# Calculating with collapsed rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm working with simple `Excel` formulae where I have 4 tables, with 4 subtotals. When expanded, the calculations work fine, but when collapsed, it seems that the calculation is unable to locate any values, therefore it's returning results as `"0"`.

Is there any way to make the calculation return the same result, regardless of whether the tables are nested or not?

I have tried with both the below formulae, and they are giving me the same issue:

`=IFERROR(IF(SUBTOTAL(101,[Shortcut])>2,ROUNDUP(SUBTOTAL(101,[Shortcut]),0),ROUND(SUBTOTAL(101,[Shortcut])-0.01,0)),"-")`

`=IFERROR(IF(SUBTOTAL(101,F16:F20)>2,ROUNDUP(SUBTOTAL(101,F16:F20),0),ROUND(SUBTOTAL(101,F16:F20)-0.01,0)),"-")`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: don't work with subtotal, but rather with sum. Subtotal is meant especially not to take into account filtered or hidden values. Sum isn't.

Comment: @Lambik, thank you!